# Setting mask on bar button item with profile picture

Tags: ios, swift

I've been struggling for a while with setting up a circular profile picture as a bar button item. The picture comes from a URL using SDWebImage. When I run the app the item appears as a square and all the other right bar button items shift left. Also ran into the same issues when trying to set the object as a UIButton. Does anybody know how I could set a circular mask on the object, and/or why the other bar button items shift left?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myAvatarButton: UIBarButtonItem! {
    didSet {
        guard let userImageURL = CurrentUser.shared.imageURL else {
            return
        }
        let avatarImage = UIImageView()
        avatarImage.sd_setImage(with: userImageURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "noProfilePhoto"), options: [.refreshCached, .retryFailed, .highPriority]) { [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            self?.myAvatarButton.image = image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Simulator Screenshot]
[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was getting the image programmatically from a URL this was a little tricky. Turns out the easiest way was to embed a UIImageView inside a View which can be inserted via storyboard into the navigation bar. From there, I created an IBOutlet and changed the corner radius. Also the other bar buttons were no longer shifted over after adjusting the image view's width.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` add `myAvatarButton.clipsToBounds = true` might work.

But the better approach would be using `customView` in your `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
...
let avatarImage = UIImageView()
avatarImage.layer.clipsToBounds = true
avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImage.frame.width / 2
...
```

It should set cornerRadius to the exact value to have your view circular.